# Look for Style Changes in Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

Is there any way when programming MS Word to list the points in the text where a change in character style occurs?

I'm programmatically trying to analyze a paragraph to retrieve all the contiguous blocks of text that have the same style - in other words, split the paragraph at the points where the text style changes. At the moment the way I'm doing it is to take each character and compare its style with the previous character - if the name of the style is different, I know I've found a point to split the results at. That works but is horrendously inefficient (for every character, you have to do a full string comparison of the style name).   I'm wondering if there's a way in the Word object model to solve this problem without comparing every character?

The approximate code I'm currently using is as follows (It's C# code: I'm using COM Interop against Word 2003, but I'd be equally happy with a solution in VBA since once I know in principle how to do it, converting to C# should be easy. )

```
// used to store the results as we go
StringBuilder currentText = new StringBuilder();
string currentStyle = null;

// range contains the Range I want to split up
foreach (Range charRng in range.Characters)
{
    string style = charRng.get_Style().NameLocal;
    if (style == currentStyle)
    {
        currentText.Append(charRng.Text);
    }
    else
    {
              AddTextBlockToMyResults(currentStyle, currentText.ToString());
        currentText = new StringBuilder(charRng.Text);
        currentStyle = style;
    }
}
AddTextBlockToMyResults(currentStyle, currentText.ToString());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What version(s) of Office were used to create the Word docs?

If it's Office 2007 or later (or, you can convert the docs to that format) then an office document is really just a .zip archive. If you open a .docx file with an archive utility like WinRAR, you'll see that it has a directory structure like:

```
_rels
customXml
docProps
word
|_ document.xml
```

That document.xml is an [Open Office XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML) file that contains all the text and reference to styles in your Word doc. I bet you could parse that XML a heck of a lot faster than doing what you're doing now.

Comment: Cunning :-) Yes, performance-wise that'd be massively more efficient.  Lots of work though as I'd have to understand and then write code to parse the document.xml, so a solution that uses the Word object model would be preferable. I'll consider your idea as a last resort.

Comment: Well, I understand your reticence to switch paths... but I don't think it would be as bad as all that. You wouldn't really have to actually understand the full XSD or know what all the tags meant - as long as you could pick out which tag(s) meant a change in style. I bet you could mock up a dummy document with a few style changes and see how Word implements them. At that point you're just looking for the tags that you care about and can probably ignore the rest. At any rate good luck :-), the Office COM layer is not the friendliest.

Comment: AFter some looking at the docx format, I agree with you. The Office COM layer has given me no end of problems (I think mainly due to lack of decent documentation) whereas the document.xml file is almost self-documenting. Probably well worth the effort going down that path instead.